# How to make long press gesture on alert button?

Tags: swift3, alert

Is it possible to make long press gesture on alert button?
Or maybe it is possible to put my own button to alert by using `alert.addAction`?

Answer (score 0):

A UIAlertController's alert view doesn't belong to you, so you can't make this sort of modification. But it is just a presented view controller. If you want to take charge of this sort of thing, use your own custom presented view controller. It can look and act just like an alert controller's view. Example here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7